# Android WebView info (WebKit, browser engine)

Tags: android, android-webview

I try to figure out how I can just get info about WebView (such as WebKit version and browser engine version) during app execution.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

you can use following code to find the webkit

```
WebView webView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
String useragent=webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
```

The user agent will look like this

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; SM-N900 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Beside this following [link](http://jimbergman.net/webkit-version-in-android-version/) can also help you to see the respective webkit in android versions.